# java geospatial 2D kernel densisty estimation

Tags: java, math, geospatial, geo

I need to develop a 2d kernel density estimation in java to give some spatial points. It would calculate the discrete 2d kde and plot over a geo map the density.  To do this I propose to use a gaussian kernel or quartic kernel.  I've read some paper about this, one can be found at http://geog.ucsb.edu/~chris/Lecture4_210C_Spring2011_PointPatternIntensity.pdf
. But I cannot understand the procedure.

Comment: From the FAQ: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Have you looked into the expectation maximization (EM) algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the link below for a simple description of the equation used in `ArcGIS` to calculate point densities using a KDE. They use a quartic function.

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=98735

Here is the Java code for that function, where `Distance` is the distance between the centre of a raster grid point for which density should be calculated, and a point object:-

```
private Double densitycalc(Double Distance, int BandWidth){
        double K;
        double DensityValue = 0;
        K = 3/(Math.PI*Math.pow(BandWidth, 2));
        DensityValue = K*Math.pow(1-Math.pow(Distance/BandWidth, 2), 2);
        return DensityValue;            
    }
```

Hope it helps.